# Does pdf converge to the normal pdf for the sample mean?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

I am watching MIT ocw lectures by Prof. Tsitsiklis on probability (youtube link is below).

My doubt is regarding a point he makes in the lecture on the Central Limit Theorem.

He says:
*The Central Limit theorem is a statement about CDFs, not PMFs or PDFs.*

My doubt is this:
Consider a continuous random variable with a pdf that is differentiable everywhere.
If we write the $$S_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n$$
and then $$Z_n = (S_n-E[S_n])/\text{standardev}(S_n),$$
Then the CDF of $Z_n$ will converge to that of the standard normal.

Now the PDF of $Z_n$ will be the derivative of the CDF of $Z_n.\,$ So the PDF of $Z_n$ should converge to that of the standard normal.
Now $S_n$ is linear function of $Z_n$, so will the PDF of $S_n$ not be a normal distribution?

For reference:
[MIT ocw Probability](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tx7zzD4aeiA&list=PLUl4u3cNGP60A3XMwZ5sep719_nh95qOe&index=66)
About the 8 min mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, if the variables being summed are continuous, then their sum is also continuous: you can state the CLT as a result on the convergence of the pdf.

In general, however, you need to use the cdf.

For example, if you are summing discrete variables, their sum is a discrete variable (even if the number of summands is large). In this case, the sum has a pmf, not a pdf (a convolution of pmfs, see https://www.statlect.com/glossary/convolutions). Hence, speaking of convergence of a sequence of pmfs to a pdf does not make sense.